# Ceilometer event publisher

Tags: openstack

Can anyone help me sort this problem out?
I am trying to install Ceilometer. I have install Gnocchi already.
When I tried to restart the Ceilometer-agent-notification service, following messages are shown:

```
    tail -f /var/log/ceilometer/ceilometer-agent-notification.log
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.369 11761 WARNING stevedore.named [-] Could not load panko
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.370 11761 ERROR ceilometer.pipeline.base [-] Unable to load publisher panko://: stevedore.exception.NoMatches: No 'ceilometer.event.publisher' driver found, looking for 'panko'
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.370 11761 ERROR ceilometer.pipeline.base Traceback (most recent call last):
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.370 11761 ERROR ceilometer.pipeline.base   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ceilometer/pipeline/base.py", line 124, in __init__
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.370 11761 ERROR ceilometer.pipeline.base     self.publishers.append(publisher_manager.get(p))
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.370 11761 ERROR ceilometer.pipeline.base   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ceilometer/pipeline/base.py", line 179, in get
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.370 11761 ERROR ceilometer.pipeline.base     'ceilometer.%s.publisher' % self._purpose)
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.370 11761 ERROR ceilometer.pipeline.base   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ceilometer/publisher/__init__.py", line 35, in get_publisher
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.370 11761 ERROR ceilometer.pipeline.base     loaded_driver = driver.DriverManager(namespace, parse_result.scheme)
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.370 11761 ERROR ceilometer.pipeline.base   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore/driver.py", line 61, in __init__
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.370 11761 ERROR ceilometer.pipeline.base     warn_on_missing_entrypoint=warn_on_missing_entrypoint
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.370 11761 ERROR ceilometer.pipeline.base   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore/named.py", line 89, in __init__
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.370 11761 ERROR ceilometer.pipeline.base     self._init_plugins(extensions)
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.370 11761 ERROR ceilometer.pipeline.base   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore/driver.py", line 113, in _init_plugins
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.370 11761 ERROR ceilometer.pipeline.base     (self.namespace, name))
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.370 11761 ERROR ceilometer.pipeline.base stevedore.exception.NoMatches: No 'ceilometer.event.publisher' driver found, looking for 'panko'
    2020-09-13 21:34:12.370 11761 ERROR ceilometer.pipeline.base
```

Any idea to help me out?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Panko is the storage facility for events, just like Gnocchi is the storage facility for samples. It would seem that your Ceilometer configuration wants to publish events to Panko, but Panko is not installed.

Either install Panko or remove references to Panko from the pipeline file(s) under /etc/ceilometer.